# Extended Kalman Filter for estimating angle using tan measurement function and two measurements

Tags: estimation, covariance, kalman-filter, nonlinear

I'm attempting to implement an extended Kalman filter (EKF) to estimate an angle $\alpha$ given measurements of two scalars $x$ and $y$ where the measurement function is $\alpha=atan(\frac{y}{x})$. With the measurement function in the form $y=h(x)$, this gives the following

$$\frac{y}{x}=tan(\alpha)$$

This is a case of requiring two measurements for the scalar state to be observable, but not being able to reconstruct two measurements from the a priori or predicted state. Is it possible to implement a filter for a measurement function of this form and, if so, how would one approach it?

Given that the measurement covariances for both $x$ and $y$ are known could I treat $\frac{y}{x}$ as a measurement with an associated covariance?

Thanks in advance!